# Php echo a href to get both url and target from a database

Tags: php

So far I have;

```
echo '<a href="' . $nav['link'] . '">';
```

The link is pulled from the database, I also want the target to be pulled from the database, how do I go about doing that?

The reason being is I have a text box on the article submitter that's value is "_blank" when ticked, in the database "target" has a default value of "_self". I want it so when I post an article, I can choose weather it will be opened in a new window or not. All of the information is stored in MySQL.

Sorry if that seems confusing, I've been at it all day, very fried.

Comment: it is too confusing what exactly you want ?

Answer (score 1):

try

target can be `_blank` or `_self` as you want

```
echo '<a href="' . $nav['link'] . '" target="'.$nav['target'].'">';
```

or try here target can be `blank` or `self` as you want

```
echo '<a href="' . $nav['link'] . '" target=_"'.$nav['target'].'">';
```

Comment: I tried that, for some reason it's only doing _blank, even after manually editing in the database it only opens in a new window.

Comment: echo '<a href="' . $nav['link'] . '" target="'. $nav['target'] .'">';

Comment: its looks fine to me if the $nav['target'] will be _self than it will open in same tab or try

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why It's not working, I've tried changing the value of the checkbox to "_self", manually changing the database records, and they are still opening in new tabs.

Comment: @user1654748 try this is the life saving for developer https://getfirebug.com/downloads

Comment: It's even appearing in view source as target="_self", tried cross browser, still opening in a new tab.

Comment: @user1654748 check this http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/selftop.html your code should work fine

Comment: Thanks for all your help, and sorry for wasting your time, the problem wasn't with the code it was with me, once I deleted the old records and posted new ones it started working, not sure why it didn't work bu editing records, but it's working now.

Comment: @user1654748 np... if i solved your problem than you can accept answr by click on the right mark below the vote and upvote the helpful

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `target` attribute for `anchor` tag and fetch/put value of the field target from database. (assuming the target value is stored in field called `target`:

```
echo '<a href="' . $nav['link'] . '" target="'. $nav['target'] .'">';
```

Comment: I tried that, for some reason it's only doing _blank, even after manually editing in the database it only opens in a new window

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="' . $nav['link'] . '" target="'. $nav['target'] .'">';
```

use target attributes to se whether you want to reload page in same window or in tab

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you also sanitize your input/output (escape/remove any special characters and html tags). If the links are user generated then you may be subject to some nasty HTML injection allowing them to print whatever they like on your page.

So if you havent thought about that yet, a quick search on Stackoverflow will provide a lot of examples.

Comment: If the link is user generated then the user can just do this:

`$nav['link'] = '#"> This text will output onto your page and i can embed anything i want!'`

Right?
So when accepting any user input make sure its not malicious. (The user had enough answers to his question so I thought I would suggest something in addition)